# Neither Advanced Search nor Search Builder offer option to save as Smart Group

Tags: smartgroups, search-builder, advanced-search

The documentation says I should be able to save a search as a Smart Group, but I don't see an option anywhere to do so. I've used both Advanced Search and Search Builder. Neither results screen offers anything to click or select to save.

On WordPress 5.2.1 and CiviCRM  5.13.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation here https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/smart-groups/#creating-smart-groups at step 6 it says it's a choice in the actions dropdown. If you don't see that option, check that you have `CiviCRM:edit groups` permission.

Comment: Thanks. I actually just stumbled across the actions menu again and found that as an option. That it was buried with many other options meant my first glance through missed that option.